# Failed file transfer from Rpi to Filezilla server

Tags: pi-zero-w, file-sharing, tftp

I need to transfer files from Rpi to my computer. Rpi is connected to my computer with wifi. The FileZilla server is logged in into. But in the terminal when I run the FTPlib file I get this error:
" socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

```
import ftplib
server = '127.0.0.1'
username = 'localhost'
password = 'hello123'
ftp_connection = ftplib.FTP(server, username, password)
remote_path = "C:\Users\sai\Desktop\ImageS"
ftp_connection.cwd(remote_path)
fh = open("/home/pi/Desktop/ImageS/test.txt", 'rb')
ftp_connection.storbinary('STOR test.txt', fh)
fh.close()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70190/discussion-on-question-by-sushrut-failed-file-transfer-from-rpi-to-filezilla-se). Please note that all relevant information (including that solicited by comments) should be edited into the question body itself. Please do not expect the readers of your question to follow a long trail of comments to gather what is relevant to give an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does work with FileZilla in principal, I've just run it up on a Windows VM with FileZilla Server and a Pi with Python3. You'll need some configuring though.

`server` needs to be the IP address of the FTP server

The `username` and `password` need to be the ones configured in FileZilla settings. These are not the same ones as the 'admin interface' ones. Go to `edit / users` in the menu bar and add yourself a user, password and set a directory to act as their home `/`. The home directory is where you'll end up when you connect. You may want to grant write permissions to this too.

in `edit /settings` leave port 21 in place and go to the passive mode settings and configure a port range. I used 50000->50100 since I don't have anything there.

You'll also need to configure the Windows firewall to accept traffic on port 21 and the same range of other ports for Passive mode.

the `remote_path` variable needs to be based on the `home` you set for the user. So say you set the home to `c:\ftp` and you wanted the files in `c:\ftp\dogs` you set `remote_path` to `/dogs` (note the slashes don't mix to well between Linux and Windows).